# Which is faster for OpenCV: PThreads, OpenMP or TBB?

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, pthreads, openmp, tbb-flow-graph

I'm using OpenCV on my Raspberry Pi 3 which has 4 cores. Right now it is compiled with PThreads. Would OpenMP or TBB perform better? Or does it depend?

I'm mostly doing things like color conversions, median blurs, cascade trackers and median flow trackers.

I'm asking because compiling each takes forever and risks breaking everything.
Is it possible to compile and use a different build of OpenCV without affecting whats currently installed (I'm using Python bindings if it matters)?

Comment: For your operations, go with tbb: https://www.theimpossiblecode.com/blog/intel-tbb-on-raspberry-pi/  You can have as many versions of OpenCV as you want on your machine. Just point Python to the version you want to use.

Comment: cool, that was the article that was tempting me, I guess I'll give it a shot

Comment: the link above incorrectly suggests to sym-link `libtbb.so` to `libtbb.so.2`. It's not recommended, please use libtbb.so as is (as a linker script)